# separate js file for front page

Tags: drupal

I am working on a drupal 7 site and am very new to this. I need to create a totally separate home page from the rest of the site. I notice the head is built in the html.tpl.php file where all the scripts are loaded. I would rather not load scripts to the rest of the site that will only be used on the front page. Also I have found that drupal adds some code to the end of my script rendering it useless.

/js/image_scale.js?lwhgie"

What is going on here and how do get better control of this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add a couple of points:

If you want to aggregate your homepage JS (which you may or may not) then you shouldn't add the stylesheets manually to the template file. You can add them in `hook_preprocess_page()`, something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_front']) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
    drupal_add_js($path . '/MYMODULE1.js');
    drupal_add_js($path . '/MYMODULE2.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

> Also I have found that drupal adds some code to the end of my script rendering it useless.
>
> /js/image_scale.js?lwhgie"

That shouldn't render your script useless. From the comments in [`drupal_get_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/6):

> A dummy query-string is added to filenames, to gain control over
>   browser-caching. The string changes on every update or full cache
>   flush, forcing browsers to load a new copy of the files, as the
>   URL changed. Files that should not be cached (see drupal_add_js())
>   get time() as query-string instead, to enforce reload on every
>   page request.

Comment: I will try this solution. What is MYMODULE and module...? I can see MYMODULE1.js is the js file I want to add. What are the differences betwenn these variables.

Comment: can I do this with a css file?

Comment: I did a little testing and added the jquery library through the .info file and found my script started working. Why is that? I thought jquery can with drupal standard...?

Comment: @user980988 MYMODULE was just a token for your module's name, with two arbitrarily named JS files. You can add CSS in a similar way, but to be honest it's easier to add both the JS and CSS earlier than the page preprocess. What's generating the content for the front page? (btw yeah, jQuery should be there by standard, though you should reference it by `jQuery` rather than `$`).

Comment: When you say module do you mean the theme..? I'm not building a module here. Sorry for my ignorance but very new to this and all the terminology.

Comment: function fource_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_home']) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'fource');
    drupal_add_js($path . 'js/image_scale.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}

Comment: @user980988 MYMODULE can be either a theme or module name, sorry for not being clear. What's your front page content? Is it a node? A view? A panel? (If so, what kind?)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new template called `page--front.tpl.php` in your theme folder and this will be your template for the homepage. Now you can add/remove any html markup you want. for more info take a look here: http://drupal.org/node/1089656 . Also, you could "tell" drupal to use your custom template file using `hook_preprocess_page()` in `template.php` file in your theme folder. See the comments on the link I posted earlier

Comment: I am using the page--front.tpl.php template file but I am also using panels. Not sure if that matters but I'm having trouble getting the preprocess function to work.